# How to use Mapserver+Openstreetmap for tracking service effectively?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, mapserver, tracking, mapfile

I have got Asset tracking installations for many clients.
The availability of GIS map data for every client location seems to be the tough part. I have got a MapServer WMS installation.

Can I use OSM data behind mapserver? Also I need to timely update with latest OSM data.
Is there any mapfile (MapServer map style configuration file) for OSM data?
And is PostgreSQL/PostGIS also a better option to include?

Update: I followed exactly the instructions on http://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/wiki/RenderingOsmDataUbuntu as advised by mapper. Everything worked fine. Got the osm-gooogle.map. 
But, when I browsed `http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/var/www/osm-demo/mapserver-utils-svn/osm-google.map&mode=browse&template=openlayers&layers=all`
There was few things to change in the generated mapfile. Mainly, the IMAGEPATH & IMAGEURL were inside METADATA tag. Moved them outside to WEB tag and everything worked fine. It started drawing Google styled map from OSM data stored in local PostGres DB.

Comment: Did you already tried http://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/wiki/RenderingOsmData or would shapefiles be an option to you?

If I understand you right, you want to switch to OSM without the need to setup a new infrastructure, right?

Comment: Yes, I saw that. That one says outdated and to follow http://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/wiki/RenderingOsmDataUbuntu

Comment: And why doesn't worked it for you or do you have different requirements?

Comment: I am working the latter one. Not much familiar with Linux. Hope will succeed.

Comment: Sorry but you left a lot of things unclear. Pretty hard to help you :/

Comment: @Mapper I followed http://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/wiki/RenderingOsmDataUbuntu There was few things to change in the generated mapfile. Mainly, the IMAGEPATH & IMAGEURL were inside METADATA tag. Moved them outside to WEB tag and everything worked fine. It started drawing Google styled map from OSM data stored in local PostGres DB. Thank you Mapper

Comment: I didn't did/wrote anything meaningful, so it wasn't me ;)

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite tell what our question is, but here is an attempt to answer it. I am assuming you want a web-map with points overlaid on top.

You can load OSM tiles from a variety of sources. For example, say you use Leaflet you could load a map with an OSM baselayer using the following approach: http://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/getting-started-with-leaflet/

If you wanted to show the vehicle locations as points on a map, you could pull this data from Postgres/PostGIS. You would need a server side script to output this data. A simple approach would be to use a php script that outputs `json`. Then, you could style these points on the client side in Leaflet.

If you wanted more sophisticated styling, you could use Mapserver to style the data (but I would need to know more about what you are trying to achieve).

Comment: By simply adding OSM tiles, can we geocode/reverse geocode my tracking/playback locations?

Comment: No, tiles are just images. They don't contain any meta-data. For geocoding/reverse-geocoding you need address data. Take a look at [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim).